# Raster loaded in ArcMap 10.2.1 not showing decimal places for value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I have an IMG format raster that I am loading into ArcMap 10.2.1. The pixel type and depth, as reported by the Source tab in Layer Properties is 32-bit floating point. The values, as reported in the Symbology tab and Identify window are integers, where I was expecting non-zero values to the right of the decimal point. For example, ArcMap gives me a value of 21.000000, whereas if I open the same image in a different GIS package like QGIS, the value for the same pixel is listed as 21.345664.

Has anyone encountered this issue?